# AWS EMR HDFS Excluding datanode DatanodeInfoWithStorage Error (UnknownHostException: ip-172-31-23-85.ec2.internal<unresolved>:9866)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-emr

I am trying to create file from spring boot to aws emr hdfs but i got this below error: UnknownHostException: ip-172-31-23-85.ec2.internal/:9866

Abandoning BP-1515286748-172.31.29.184-1681364405694:blk_1073741829_1005

Excluding datanode DatanodeInfoWithStorage[172.31.23.85:9866,DS-798b58b3-ee0d-4dc2-8e4f-20379073f001,DISK]

In EMR one master node and three datanotes all are up and running

Can you please help me

I have tried from spring boot using below code:

```
@Test
void testHadoop() {
    try {
        Map<String, String> val = new HashMap<>();
        val.put("name", "kannan");
        try (FSDataOutputStream outputStream = fileSystem.create(new Path("/user/hadoop/test.txt"), true)) {
            outputStream.writeBytes(gson.toJson(val));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

the file is created in hdfs but getting error

````
2023-04-13T14:14:40.724+05:30  WARN 15232 --- [       Thread-5] org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer      : Exception in createBlockOutputStream blk_1073741829_1005

java.net.UnknownHostException: ip-172-31-23-85.ec2.internal/<unresolved>:9866
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:591) ~[hadoop-common-3.3.4.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.createSocketForPipeline(DataStreamer.java:253) ~[hadoop-hdfs-client-3.3.4.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.createBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1774) ~[hadoop-hdfs-client-3.3.4.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1728) ~[hadoop-hdfs-client-3.3.4.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.run(DataStreamer.java:713) ~[hadoop-hdfs-client-3.3.4.jar:na]

2023-04-13T14:14:40.725+05:30  WARN 15232 --- [       Thread-5] org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer      : Abandoning BP-1515286748-172.31.29.184-1681364405694:blk_1073741829_1005
2023-04-13T14:14:41.049+05:30  WARN 15232 --- [       Thread-5] org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer      : Excluding datanode DatanodeInfoWithStorage[172.31.23.85:9866,DS-798b58b3-ee0d-4dc2-8e4f-20379073f001,DISK]
2023-04-13T14:14:41.473+05:30  WARN 15232 --- [       Thread-5] org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer      : Exception in createBlockOutputStream blk_1073741830_1006

java.net.UnknownHostException: ip-172-31-23-88.ec2.internal/<unresolved>:9866
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:591) ~[hadoop-common-3.3.4.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.createSocketForPipeline(DataStreamer.java:253) ~[hadoop-hdfs-client-3.3.4.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.createBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1774) ~[hadoop-hdfs-client-3.3.4.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1728) ~[hadoop-hdfs-client-3.3.4.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.run(DataStreamer.java:713) ~[hadoop-hdfs-client-3.3.4.jar:na]

2023-04-13T14:14:41.473+05:30  WARN 15232 --- [       Thread-5] org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer      : Abandoning BP-1515286748-172.31.29.184-1681364405694:blk_1073741830_1006
2023-04-13T14:14:41.735+05:30  WARN 15232 --- [       Thread-5] org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer      : Excluding datanode DatanodeInfoWithStorage[172.31.23.88:9866,DS-4839d3eb-5351-4334-bb54-56f0e80a524c,DISK]
2023-04-13T14:14:42.155+05:30  WARN 15232 --- [       Thread-5] org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer      : Exception in createBlockOutputStream blk_1073741831_1007

java.net.UnknownHostException: ip-172-31-22-39.ec2.internal/<unresolved>:9866
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:591) ~[hadoop-common-3.3.4.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.createSocketForPipeline(DataStreamer.java:253) ~[hadoop-hdfs-client-3.3.4.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.createBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1774) ~[hadoop-hdfs-client-3.3.4.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1728) ~[hadoop-hdfs-client-3.3.4.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.run(DataStreamer.java:713) ~[hadoop-hdfs-client-3.3.4.jar:na]

2023-04-13T14:14:42.155+05:30  WARN 15232 --- [       Thread-5] org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer      : Abandoning BP-1515286748-172.31.29.184-1681364405694:blk_1073741831_1007
2023-04-13T14:14:42.480+05:30  WARN 15232 --- [       Thread-5] org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer      : Excluding datanode DatanodeInfoWithStorage[172.31.22.39:9866,DS-7fa474ae-925c-44c3-b430-cf5d96953ef0,DISK]
2023-04-13T14:14:42.751+05:30  WARN 15232 --- [       Thread-5] org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer      : DataStreamer Exception

org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: File /user/hadoop/test.txt could only be written to 0 of the 1 minReplication nodes. There are 3 datanode(s) running and 3 node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:2315)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirWriteFileOp.chooseTargetForNewBlock(FSDirWriteFileOp.java:294)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:2970)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:904)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:595)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:604)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:572)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:556)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1093)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:1175)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:1099)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:3316)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1612) ~[hadoop-common-3.3.4.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1558) ~[hadoop-common-3.3.4.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1455) ~[hadoop-common-3.3.4.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:242) ~[hadoop-common-3.3.4.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:129) ~[hadoop-common-3.3.4.jar:na]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy85.addBlock(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:530) ~[hadoop-hdfs-client-3.3.4.jar:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:422) ~[hadoop-common-3.3.4.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:165) ~[hadoop-common-3.3.4.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:157) ~[hadoop-common-3.3.4.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:95) ~[hadoop-common-3.3.4.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:359) ~[hadoop-common-3.3.4.jar:na]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy86.addBlock(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.addBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1088) ~[hadoop-hdfs-client-3.3.4.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DataStreamer.java:1915) ~[hadoop-hdfs-client-3.3.4.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1717) ~[hadoop-hdfs-client-3.3.4.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.run(DataStreamer.java:713) ~[hadoop-hdfs-client-3.3.4.jar:na]

org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /user/hadoop/test.txt could only be written to 0 of the 1 minReplication nodes. There are 3 datanode(s) running and 3 node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:2315)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirWriteFileOp.chooseTargetForNewBlock(FSDirWriteFileOp.java:294)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:2970)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:904)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:595)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:604)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:572)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:556)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1093)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:1175)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:1099)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:3316)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1612)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1558)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:242)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:129)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy85.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:530)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:157)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:359)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy86.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.addBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1088)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DataStreamer.java:1915)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1717)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.run(DataStreamer.java:713)
2023-04-13T14:14:43.030+05:30  INFO 15232 --- [ntContainer#0-2] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Waiting for workers to finish.
2023-04-13T14:14:43.560+05:30  INFO 15232 --- [ntContainer#0-2] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Successfully waited for workers to finish.
2023-04-13T14:14:43.561+05:30  INFO 15232 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Shutdown ignored - container is already stopped```
````

Comment: Are you running your unit test on the cluster? If not, then you simply won't be able to resolve EC2 internal addresses, as the error says. Besides that, HDFS files should be at least 128 MB in size, at the smallest. 1 map entry is only a few bytes, so I'm confused why you think you'll need Hadoop here rather than RDS or DynamoDB

Comment: Thanks. the issue is hostname so i have updated hostname to public ip using    `<property>
   <name>dfs.datanode.hostname</name>
   <value>ip</value>
 </property> `